# Vermin Lord has Pincer Claws ability in table that is missing in text

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, errata

Page 74 of *The Book of Vile Darkness* shows the table for The Vermin Lord and at 8th level the ability "pincer claws" is gained.  However, in the accompanying ability descriptions for the class, that ability is conspicuously absent.  Does anyone know if any official errata exists that explains this ability?  Incidentally, I just give my vermin lord (2)1D6 natural claw attacks that if successful can attempt a grapple as a free action.  If there is any errata known of I would appreciate the knowledge, thanks.

Comment: [Relevant](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?421671-We-finally-found-it)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 1):

There are no official erratas for this ability that I am aware of. The only indication of the meaning of this ability *MAY* be is in *Sandstorm* where on page 191 the entry for Wasteland Crawler has the following attack options:

> **Attack:**  Pincer  claw  +13  melee  (2d6+8)  or  tail  sting  +13  melee (1d6+8 plus 1d6 fire)
>
> **Full  Attack:**  2  pincer  claws  +13  melee  (2d6+8)  and  tail  sting +11 melee (1d6+4 plus 1d6 fire

This is as far as I'm aware the only reference to Pincer Claws.

---

*I'd be fine with the house rule you presented.*

Comment: I think that a natural attack with the base damage equal to a greatsword is a bit high.  Plus, improved natural attack feat would increase the damage to 2d8 which is the equivalent of a fullblade.  A bit high.

Comment: @JosephDouglas Eh, vermin lords aren’t exactly melee powerhouses to begin with, and base weapon damage doesn’t matter that much. But anyway, the waste crawler (anhydrut) is already Large, so the base damage for a Medium set of pincer claws would be 1d8 instead.

Comment: The creature is known as “waste crawler” rather than “wasteland crawler,” by the way. Also known as the anhydrut, also known as the dumbest conceivable inevitable and a distinct mar on an otherwise awesome creature concept.